# Installing chromium-browser:armhf and libwidevinecdm0 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install chromium-browser:armhf and libwidevinecdm0 on my Raspberry Pi (Ubuntu 21.10 64 bit) by doing the following command:

```bash
sudo apt install chromium-browser:armhf libwidevinecdm0
```

According to [this instruction](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-os-64-bit/?unapproved=1580594&moderation-hash=fb33f27a8a6aaeef5dd2e38123f6ca6d#comment-1580594).

But I'm getting the following output:

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> E: Unable to locate package chromium-browser:armhf
> E: Unable to locate package libwidevinecdm0

EDIT:
It seems that there is new 64-bit version (from https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=347736) is there a way to install it on Raspberry pi 4 with Ubuntu 22.10 64-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those instructions are for Raspberry Pi OS, not Ubuntu.

You could enable `armhf` on Ubuntu with

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf && sudo apt update
```

but that won’t help since, as far as I can tell from a quick look, Ubuntu doesn’t ship `libwidevinecdm0`.

If you want Chrome with Widevine on your Raspberry Pi, install Raspberry Pi OS.

If you really want to try installing Widevine on Ubuntu, you can try the packages available [in the Raspberry Pi OS repositories](http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/w/widevine/); however, these are built for Raspberry Pi OS, not Ubuntu, so there’s no guarantee they’ll work there.

Comment: thanks to https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=347736 it seems that there is new 64-bit version that came out, is there a way to install it on Ubuntu?

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: is there a way to "connect" it to `apt` so if there is an update it will be installed automatically or install the chromium version that comes with widevine built in?